# Nested InnerHTML

Tags: javascript, php

This is my code and it is not working properly

```
function addInput_tagh(sel_number_tagh,sel_status_tagh)
{

    var tr=document.createElement("TR"); 
    var td=document.createElement("TD"); 
    a = document.getElementById('count_ref_tagh').value;
    tr.id = 'RT'+a;
    var TRid = 'RT'+a;

    td.innerHTML = 'وضعیت: &nbsp;<SELECT id="selstatus_tagh['+a
        +']" name="selstatus_tagh['+a+']">'
        +sel_status_tagh.replace('value=1', 'value=1 selected')
        +'</select>&nbsp;نوع سند: &nbsp;<select name="sanad_type'+a
        +'" id="sanad_type'+a
        +'" onchange="refrences_sanadtype(this.value, \''+a
        +'\', \''+sel_number_tagh+'\', \''+sel_status_tagh
        +'\');"><option value="sanadtype1">کتاب</option>'
        +'<option value="sanadtype2">آدرس اینترنتی</option></select><span id="sp'+a
        +'">'+'&nbsp; &loz; سند: <input type="text" size="20" id="ref_sanad_tagh['+a
        +']" name="ref_sanad_tagh['+a
        +']" value="" readonly> <input type="hidden"  size="5" id="ref_codesanad_tagh['+a
        +']" name="ref_codesanad_tagh['+a
        +']" value="" readonly ><input style="cursor:pointer; '
        +'margin-right:3px;" title="انتخاب سند" type="button" '
        +'value="انتخاب سند" onclick="ShowModal_sanad_tagh(\''+a
        +'\');" >&nbsp; &loz; جلد: <input type="text" size="5" id="ref_jeld_tagh['+a
        +']"  name="ref_jeld_tagh['+a
        +']" value="" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&loz; جزء:  '
        +'<input type="text" size="5" id="ref_joz_tagh['+a
        +']" name="ref_joz_tagh['+a
        +']" value="" >&nbsp;&nbsp; &loz; صفحه: <input '
        +'type="text" size="5" id="ref_fpage_tagh['+a
        +']" name="ref_fpage_tagh['+a
        +']" value="" > تا <input type="text" size=5 id="ref_epage_tagh['+a
        +']" name="ref_epage_tagh['+a
        +']" value="" ><input type="text" size="20" id="ref_url_tagh['+a
        +']" name="ref_url_tagh['+a
        +']" value=""> <input type="button" title="تقطیع اصطلاح" '
        +'style="cursor:pointer;" value="تقطیع اصطلاح" onclick="Showhide_tagh(\''+a
        +'\');"> <input type="button" title="نمایش متن" '
        +'style="cursor:pointer;" value="نمايش متن" onclick="show_matn_tagh('+a
        +')" > <a href="javascript:void(0);" '
        +'onclick="tbody_tagti.removeChild(tbody_tagti.rows[\'RT'+a
        +'\']);" ><image title="حذف منبع" src="images/delete.png" '
        +'style="width:20; height:20;" border=0 alt="حذف"></a> <br><div id="textcut_tagh['+a
        +']" style="display:none"><textarea id="term_textcut_tagh['+a
        +']" name="term_textcut_tagh['+a
        +']" style="width:100%;" class="tinymce" >&nbsp; </textarea> </div>'
        +'</span>';

    tr.appendChild(td); 

    document.getElementById('tbody_tagti').appendChild(tr); 
    document.getElementById('count_ref_tagh').value = 
        parseInt(document.getElementById('count_ref_tagh').value) + 1;
}

function refrences_sanadtype(santype, TRid,sel_number_tagh,sel_status_tagh)
{

    var td = document.getElementById("sp"+TRid); 
    var x = document.getElementById("sanad_type"+TRid);
    var htData='&nbsp; &loz; سند: <input type="text" size="20" id="ref_sanad_tagh['+a
        +']" name="ref_sanad_tagh['+a+']" value="" readonly> '
        +'<input type="hidden"  size="5" id="ref_codesanad_tagh['+a
        +']" name="ref_codesanad_tagh['+a
        +']" value="" readonly ><input style="cursor:pointer; '
        +'margin-right:3px;" title="انتخاب سند" type="button" '
        +'value="انتخاب سند" onclick="ShowModal_sanad_tagh(\''+a
        +'\');" >&nbsp; &loz; جلد: <input type="text" size="5" id="ref_jeld_tagh['+a
        +']"  name="ref_jeld_tagh['+a
        +']" value="" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&loz; جزء:  '
        +'<input type="text" size="5" id="ref_joz_tagh['+a
        +']" name="ref_joz_tagh['+a
        +']" value="" >&nbsp;&nbsp; &loz; صفحه: <input '
        +'type="text" size="5" id="ref_fpage_tagh['+a
        +']" name="ref_fpage_tagh['+a
        +']" value="" > تا <input type="text" size=5 id="ref_epage_tagh['+a
        +']" name="ref_epage_tagh['+a
        +']" value="" > <input type="button" title="تقطیع اصطلاح" '
        +'style="cursor:pointer;" value="تقطیع اصطلاح" onclick="Showhide_tagh(\''+a
        +'\');"> <input type="button" title="نمایش متن" '
        +'style="cursor:pointer;" value="نمايش متن" onclick="show_matn_tagh('+a
        +')" > <a href="javascript:void(0);" '
        +'onclick="tbody_tagti.removeChild(tbody_tagti.rows[\'RT'+a
        +'\']);" ><image title="حذف منبع" src="images/delete.png" '
        +'style="width:20; height:20;" border=0 alt="حذف"></a> <br><div id="textcut_tagh['+a
        +']" style="display:none"><textarea id="term_textcut_tagh['+a
        +']" name="term_textcut_tagh['+a
        +']" style="width:100%;" class="tinymce" >&nbsp; </textarea> </div>';

    if(x.value == "sanadtype1"){
        td.innerHTML=htData;
            //x.value='sanadtype1';
            /*var e = document.createElement('div');
            e.innerHTML = ;
            while(e.firstChild) {
                td.appendChild(e.firstChild);
            }*/
    }

    if(x.value == "sanadtype2"){
            /*var e = document.createElement('div');
            e.innerHTML = 'test';
            while(e.firstChild) {
                td.appendChild(e.firstChild);
            }*/
        td.innerHTML = '&nbsp; &loz; آدرس منبع: <input style="direction:ltr" '
            +'type="text" size="80" id="ref_url_tagh['+a
            +']" name="ref_url_tagh['+a
            +']" value=""><input style="margin-right:10px" type="button" '
            +'title="تقطیع اصطلاح" style="cursor:pointer;" value="تقطیع اصطلاح" '
            +'onclick="Showhide_tagh(\''+a
            +'\');"> <input type="button" title="نمایش متن" '
            +'style="cursor:pointer;" value="نمايش متن" '
            +'onclick="show_matn_tagh('+a
            +')" > <a href="javascript:void(0);" '
            +'onclick="tbody_tagti.removeChild(tbody_tagti.rows[\'RT'
            +a+'\']);" ><image title="حذف منبع" src="images/delete.png" '
            +'style="width:20; height:20;" border=0 alt="حذف"></a> <br>'
            +'<div id="textcut_tagh['+a+']" style="display:none"><textarea '
            +'id="term_textcut_tagh['+a+']" name="term_textcut_tagh['+a
            +']" style="width:100%;" class="tinymce" >&nbsp; </textarea> </div>';
            //x.value='sanadtype2';
    }
}
```

the innerHTML in if clause in refrences_sanadtype function do not send the value to form post page

Comment: when/how is that function called?

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming all the work is done here to update dynamically a fragment of a form : you shoud be sure that the dom is correctely modified by inspecting it in your browser before submitting the form (using F12 should lead you to the developper tools ).
 If the form is really correctely updated, try to post it and analyze in dev tools what is really sent to the server.

Hope it helps